# PHP/MySQL/Apache/JS with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: php, visual-studio, apache, ide, lamp

I'm working on a project that uses a PHP, MySQL, Apache, and runs on a Linux server. Is there any plugin so that I can use Visual Studio as my IDE?

Preferably, it would be something free, unlike VS.PHP which apparently costs $100/year.

And, I'm running the VS 2010 beta.

Answer (score 0):

There's [this](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/).  It's also reported that VS 2010 will support PHP natively.

EDIT: I couldn't find anything more definitive than [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=392488) regarding 2010 support, but a quick google search suggests lots of people are under that impression.

Answer (score 0):

Please try our VS.Php for Visual Studio 2010 beta:

http://svn.jcxsoftware.com

Answer (score 0):

I actually reviewed VS.PHP and gave it a thumbs-down.
To be honest it did most of the stuff right but had some minor quirks like indenting problems, variable suggestion fails, etc..

Currently reviewing http://www.devsense.com/products/php-tools/download
First impression is quite good but I didn't do any decent coding in it tbh.